# Visual Studio 2010 asp.net hangs up when saving pages

Tags: asp.net, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My Visual Studio 2010 hangs up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938786/my-visual-studio-2010-hangs-up)

I was using Visual Studio 2010 for long time (about 2 years now without having any problem like that).
Four days ago suddenly VS hangs up when I'm trying to save a page (refereed to my master).
My Master File have one

> ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent"

As start.
 
And after "body" and "form" follows

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent"  runat="server">
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
<asp:SiteMapPath id="SiteMapPath1" runat="server>
</asp:Content> 
<asp:ContentPlaceHolderID="Buttons"  runat="server>
</asp:Content>  
<asp:ContentPlaceHolderID="CenterHolder"  runat="server>
</asp:Content> 
<asp:ContentPlaceHolderID="BottomHolder"  runat="server>
</asp:Content> 
</asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>
```

There is also a Default.aspx file which have the following code:

```
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
```

I use in my Default.aspx; as Default Content Holder the "MainContent"
And I'm adding the next Content Holder which is the "Buttons"
Now When I'm trying to save the Default.aspx file changes the VS hangs up sawing the small icon at the bottom trying to save.
And that's it I leave it for one all night but nothing happen (it was a time which gives me a blue screen).
I had to uninstall VS and each environment. Nothing happen... Is there anybody with the same experience?

From what I have noticed... when the problem starts the CPU usage is 100% but the memory usage is normal 199Kb

Comment: did you installed an extension recently ? if yes try to disable it. You can also run in safe mode to see if something changes, and also running with the /log argument

Comment: And I don't think you can name the content control with the same name than the contentplaceholder control, but I'm not sure

Comment: @Steve B. The ContentPlaceHolderID in the content; needs to have the same name as the ContentPlaceHolderID in the master to work. That was I was doing all the time before. Now I'll try to run with /log argument. What extension I may installed? I'm sure I understand this.

Comment: the contentplaceholderid must be equals to the id of the parent contentplaceholder, but the id of the content can be anything else

Comment: @Steve B. The problem is not starting on the "HeadContent" it starts when I'm trying to add the next content; "Buttons"

Comment: You don't remedy a closed question by asking a new one.  Next time, go back and fix your original question.

Comment: @RobertHarvey. Yes you're absolute right on that. I just fix my answer :)

Comment: @RobertHarvey. Well I did search all the relative topics but I didn't find anything to answers in my question.. Sorry. My earlier question was closed by four persons which they thought that was they right thing to do, So I have to reopen it with an other title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thing finally found the solution to problem.
Any "ContentPlaceHolder" CANNOT nested inside of a General "ContentPlaceHolder" Like I did.
That happen when install VS SP1.